# Laravel log: No rate limit is set for queue

Tags: laravel

I set up a cron job and queue in my sending email job. I also used spatie rate-limiting middleware - A job middleware to rate limit jobs.

Here's a snippet inside a job.

```
public function handle()
{
    if ($this->type == 'employee') {
        $language = $this->employee->language;
        if ($this->employee->account->language_setting) {
            $language = Language::find($this->employee->account->language_setting)->language;
        }

        Mail::to($this->employee)->locale($language)->send( new SendWeeklySurvey($this->employee, $this->user, $this->categories));
    } else {
        $language = $this->user->language;
        if ($this->user->account->language_setting) {
            $language = Language::find($this->user->account->language_setting)->language;
        }

        Mail::to($this->user->email)->locale($language)->send(new SurveySentNotification($this->user));
    }
}

public function middleware()
{
    $rateLimitedMiddleware = (new RateLimited())
        ->allow(50)
        ->everySeconds(10)
        ->releaseAfterSeconds(5);

    return [$rateLimitedMiddleware];
}
```

And here's inside `storage/logs/laravel.log`
[laravel.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmphR.png)

I don't know why it says no rate limit even if the rate limiter has been set up.
Is there a way to disable logging for the rate limit?